# error while getting the jspdf npm package : GET https://unpkg.com/jspdf@2.0.0/dist/jspdf.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: jspdf

I get a network error 404 when i upload the package with the line bellow

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

i've been using this package for more then 6 months now but it's the first time i get this issue with it.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by rolling back to the previous version of the jspdf package :

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

the new version don't work even if i add it with the version number not (@latest)

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@2.0.0/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

Comment: check the github repo: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF. It is `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.0.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>` now

Comment: tried both and both didn't work for the latest version. not the same issue but both didn't work